# Finding the height of a row in a WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Can someone please advise me on how to do this?

I have tried

```
dtgMain.RowHeight;
```

but this always returns NAN.

Comment: it returns NaN becasue of it had been set explicitely (your rows haight is always assumed by its content. once set it'll return the value.

Comment: is there anyway I can find what the assumed height of a row is?

Comment: it's just NaN - in WPF elements are allowed to have NaN as Height, it simply means that size is dictated by the contents as opposed to specify explicitely. You can try calling Measure(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity) and chec the DesiredSize after. it's not guaranteed to work though.

Answer (score 5):

Get a DataGridRow using VisualTreeHelper from data grid. Then use ActualHeight property on DataGridRow.

```
public static T GetFirstVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                return (T)child;
            }

            T childItem = GetFirstVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childItem != null) return childItem;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then:

```
DataGridRow row = GetFirstVisualChild<DataGridRow>(dtgMain);
if(row != null)
{
    row.ActualHeight;
}
```

Comment: Trying to do this but get Error 10 The type arguments for method 'OpenStackupGui.MainWindow.GetFirstVisualChild<T>(System.Windows.DependencyObject)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Did you specified type when calling GetFirstVisualChild<DataGridRow>(dtgMain);

Comment: The error is on this line in the GetFirstVisualChild method. - T childItem = GetFirstVisualChild(child);

Comment: That should be T childItem = GetFirstVisualChild<T>(child); I have updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: DataGridRow row = GetFirstVisualChild<DataGridRow>(dtgMain);
Returns null... any ideas?

Comment: If data grid does not have any row in it then it will be null. Use this method only when you have some rows in data grid.

Comment: I do have rows in data grid. Is it because Im in debug mode in visual studio so the row isnt actually rendered on the screen?

Comment: Nope tried with no breakpoints in. The datagrid is deffinately displaying rows but row still comes back null

Comment: Amit at the point I call the method the datagrid has a datasource containing rows and has drawn the rown onto the screen.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone needs the VB.NET version these days...

```
Public Shared Function GetFirstVisualChild(Of T As DependencyObject)(depObj As DependencyObject) As T
    If (depObj IsNot Nothing) Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj) - 1

            Dim child As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i)
            If (child IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf child Is T) Then

                Return CType(child, T)
            End If

            Dim childItem As T = GetFirstVisualChild(Of T)(child)
            If (childItem IsNot Nothing) Then Return childItem
        Next
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

then

```
Dim row As DataGridRow = CType(GetFirstVisualChild(Of DataGridRow)(grid), DataGridRow)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because The Grid hasn't been rendered yet. Check Out The Measure & Arrange Functions to Render the Grid before trying to get the RowHeigth.

Comment: I did think this might be the issue and tried to invalidate the grid to force it to render. Would you be able to post a little code example please?

Answer (score 1):

It's NaN because you didn't define it. If you don't set it manually it defined by the measure result of the row content.

Comment: Could you extend the answer a little please?

Answer (score 0):

Row must be displayed.
Challenge is to obtain valid instance of DataGridRow in order to access property ActualHeight.
If you do it at startup you can default with 0 like below.
In the code posted i obtain height of row, assume they all have same height to obtain an indication of number of rows displayed (i take 80% to get an approximation):

```
            int currentRow = _grid.SelectedIndex == -1 ? 0 : _grid.SelectedIndex;
            System.Windows.DependencyObject  dep = _grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(currentRow);
            var dataGridRow = dep as  DataGridRow;
            if (dataGridRow is null)
            {
                string msg = $"Cannot acces row[{currentRow}] of datagrid";
                _log.Error(msg);
                throw new AccessViolationException(msg);
            }
            int visibleRowCount = (int)(_grid.ActualHeight / dataGridRow.ActualHeight * 0.8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function as an extension method.

```cs
public static T GetFirstVisualChild<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null) return null;

    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
        if (child is T tChild)
        {
            return tChild;
        }

        var childItem = GetFirstVisualChild<T>(child);
        if (childItem != null) return childItem;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Unless you are explicitly specifying the `Height` of the `DataGridRow`, it's going to be set to `double.NaN`. If you want to set the height, the easiest way to do this is with the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `DataGrid`:

```xml
<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

If you don't have want to explicitly set the `Height`, then you will want to use the `ActualHeight` property. The difference is the `Height` is the **allowed** height of the row whereas the `ActualHeight` is the rendered height.

```cs
var row = grid.GetFirstVisualChild<DataGridRow>();

MessageBox.Show($"{row.ActualHeight}");
```